# Vue2Leaflet component does not display the map

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I'm trying to use the Vue2Leaflet component (https://vuejsexamples.com/vue-2-components-for-leaflet-maps/) but I have hard time to make it works. I could not make this simple example work, with the html file :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app" style="height: 400px">
      <v-map :zoom=13 :center="[47.413220, -1.219482]">
        <v-tilelayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"></v-tilelayer>
        <v-marker :lat-lng="[47.413220, -1.219482]"></v-marker>
      </v-map>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue2-leaflet"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the js file :

```
Vue.component('v-map', window.Vue2Leaflet.LMap)
Vue.component('v-tilelayer', window.Vue2Leaflet.TileLayer)
Vue.component('v-marker', window.Vue2Leaflet.Marker)
new Vue({ el: '#app'});
```

I made a fiddle with this basic exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/rvxc2uLk/3. 
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the "L" before `.TileLayer` also for `.Marker`.

```
Vue.component('v-map', window.Vue2Leaflet.LMap)
Vue.component('v-tilelayer', window.Vue2Leaflet.LTileLayer)
Vue.component('v-marker', window.Vue2Leaflet.LMarker)
```